# Designing URI for current logged in user in REST applications

Tags: rest, http, url

I need a URI in my REST API to retrieve the current logged in user. Usually I use [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) on resource with ID, but the client doesn't know the ID of the user.

I found the following solutions:

- By user name

  This solution uses the user name instead of the ID of the user.

  Example:

  - [Bitbucket REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.5.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp2837072): `GET /user/{userSlug}`
- With own resource

  This solution has one resource for users and one additional resource for logged in user.

  Examples:

  - [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/myself-getUser): `GET /myself`
  - [GitHub REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user): `GET /user`
  - [Stack Exchange REST API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me): `GET /me`
- With symbolic link

  This solution has a symbolic link for the ID of the user.

  Example:

  - [Confluence REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/5.4.4/#d2e90): `GET /user/current`
- With filter

  This solution uses a filter for the user name.

  Example:

  - [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/user-getUser): `GET /user?username={username}`

Which one is most RESTful? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

*It's up to you.* All the approaches are perfectly fine from a REST perspective.

According to Roy Thomas Fielding's dissertation<sup>*</sup>, *any information that can be named can be a resource*:

> [**5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers**](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)
>
> The key abstraction of information in REST is a *resource*. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time. [...]

When using `/me`, `/users/me`, `/users/myself`, `/users/current` and similars, you have a locator for the *authenticated user* and it will always identify the *concept* of an *authenticated user*, regardless of which user is authenticated.

For more flexibility, you also can support `/users/{username}`.

By the way, a similar situation was addressed in [Is using magic (me/self) resource identifiers going against REST principles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35719797/1426227)

---

<sup>* If you are interested in REST, the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Fielding's dissertation is a must-read.</sup>

Comment: is it good to use current with Restful when HTTP Get is the protocol to receive data? with some ISP caching and etc? isn't caching affect Get URL? is it safe? or should we always send user id ?

Comment: Please note that sending both username and a Authentication header is prone to spoofing attacks, if the developers did not carefully check any mismatch.

Comment: What if I have a resource related to the current user? Should I prepend always `/users/me`, like `/users/me/resources/:id`?

Answer (score 5):

I think REST URIs should uniquely identify the resource, no matter it' using `userId/email/ssn or username`, whichever attribute uniquely identify user in your system.

So, resource can be `users` (plural `/users`) and to make it singular we have below options,

If client has `userId`, resource should be something like,

```
GET - /users/{user-id}
```

If client doesn't have `userId`, but has `username`, then

```
GET - /users/{username}
```

So, as long as uri uniquely identifies user, we can use above uri patterns as a REST resource.

If, client doesn't have `userId`, `username` or `email` or any other attribute which uniquely identifies user in your system, then, we can have resource uri something like,

```
GET- /users/current
```

OR

```
GET- /users/me
```

But, in this case, client needs to have user specific TOKEN or session enabled, so that server can find user from active session or token passed in headers.
Note, we should consider this a last option.

Answer (score -9):

All are equally RESTful. REST is not about URIs, it is about *using* them RESTfully.

REST is about the client navigating application state. Part of this state may be who is the current user. All URLs can be used to get this part of application state.

Comment: REST it's all about the URIs and how objects are related to them

Comment: REST itself, as in Fieldings thesis, says nothing about the URL structure