# REST - API design to get resources for current user

Tags: rest, http, uri, api-design

We have a `FitnessClassesService` which allows scheduling fitness-training classes. There are a number of **actors** for every class:

- **The main trainer** who explains the entire workout - he does all the talking but does not necessarily do the workouts himself.
- **A substitute trainer** in case the main trainer is not available
- **Two trainers** who demonstrate the entire workout by actually doing it in the class - one for the newbies and one for old-timers
- **Two trainers** who just move around the class to clarify any doubts.

When a class is created, all the actors are also added to it. The trainers have an app from where they can see the classes which they have to participate in today (in any role).

I create classes by calling `POST /classes` .

What would be the correct REST API for getting all classes for a trainer when they open their app. These are the alternatives I considered:

- `Get /classes` - Get userId from the HTTP header and use that to get classes for the current logged-in user only. However, this does not seem very RESTful to me.
- `GET /classes/~alice` or `Get /classes/current` - From [designing-uri-for-current-logged-in-user-in-rest-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520372/designing-uri-for-current-logged-in-user-in-rest-applications) . This will only get classes represented by the "**current**" user. However, unlike the example in the linked question where "**users**" was a resource and the "**current**" user represented a specific resource, I don't feel like "**current**" represents a resource for my usecase. "**current**" for me represents all classes where I am an interested party. This sounds like I have to `filter` on the `classes` resource instead of asking for a specific resource.
- `GET /classes?actorId=alice` or `GET /classes?actorId=current` - But what if someone calls `GET /classes` . Should I verify that an actorId must always be passed. Additionally, the actorId must match the logged-in user's id. Is it okay to do such authorization based on URI parameters.
- `Get /myclasses` - Use a different URI. This means that I will be creating classes by `POST /classes` but getting classes by a different URI.

What would be the canonical way of handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the correct REST API for getting all classes for a trainer when they open their app

If you want a REST API, an early step is to think carefully about your [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).

> Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource.

Conceptually, "Alice's schedule" and "Bob's schedule" are resources.  So too is "MY schedule", but of course we have a pronoun antecedent problem.

There are two pretty straight forward ways to handle an authenticated request for "my schedule"; you can respond by redirecting to the correct resource, and you can inline the current representation of the correct resource into your response (with metadata indicating where it came from).  Those approaches are both *fine*.

(Note: RFC 7234 constrains the [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3.2) of authenticated responses, which is part of why it is "fine").

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI (so long as it conforms to the production rules defined in RFC 3986).  So all of these are fine

```
/classes/actorId=alice
/classes?actorId=alice

/classes/alice
/classes?alice
```

> Use a different URI.

Still fine.

One of the things that you need to be aware of is that [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) is tied to the URI; when you POST to `/classes`, it will invalidate your locally cached representation of `/classes` but not your locally cached representation of `/myclasses`.  Which means that when you have the same information encoded into the representations of multiple resources, those representations will not necessarily be synchronized.

> I PUT to /classes/{classId} , will it invalidate the cached response associated with /classes. Similarly, if I POST to /classes, will it invalidate the cached response associated with /classes/alice

No to both.  The hierarchy implied by similar identifiers is not real.  You describe relationships between URI via [link relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), not spelling, and there aren't currently standardized link relations that mean "these resources should be invalidated together".

> When I PUT /classes/{classId}, shouldn't the cache for GET /classes be invalidated. Otherwise GET /classes may return a stale representation of /classes/{classId}

As far as general purpose components are concerned, `/classes/{classId}` is completely unrelated to `/classes`.  Identifiers are *identifiers*, not "identifiers and also implicit link relations".

The general purpose mechanism for describing a relationship between links is a [link relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288).  So if we wanted to announce to general purpose components that the changes to this resource also invalidate cached representations of that resource, we would need something like [Linked Cache Invalidation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-linked-cache-inv-04).

But... that draft expired seven years ago without being adopted, and I haven't yet found a substitute for it.

Which in essence means that the limitations on cache invalidation are a *constraint* that you need to keep in mind when designing your resource model.  If it's important that information A and information B get invalidated together, then they need to be modeled by the same resource.

Of course, you can including caching information in your payloads, so that custom clients can know that the data is invalid; you express the link relation in your record schema, and clients that are aware of the schema can choose the appropriate action.  You can even lift that information from the body of the message to the headers, if you like.  But since none of the standard components know what your new header means, they all just ignore it (in other words, its just noise until we have a contract that both producers and consumers understand).

Comment: On your last note on cache invalidation, if I PUT to `/classes/{classId}` , will it invalidate the cached response associated with `/classes`. Similarly, if I POST to `/classes`, will it invalidate the cached response associated with `/classes/alice`. The RFC specification you linked to says that **A cache MUST invalidate the effective Request URI** . It seems to me that this does not say anything about related URIs like the examples I gave.

Comment: No, you don't get to control cache behavior by designing clever identifier spellings.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite understand. When I `PUT /classes/{classId}`, shouldn't the cache for `GET /classes` be invalidated. Otherwise `GET /classes` may return a stale representation of `/classes/{classId}`