# Referring the customer number implicitly in RESTful API

Tags: rest

GET /customers/{customer-id}

I am designing an API where the customer gets identified with the Authorization token passed in the request header. This means the above API doesn't require the `customer-id` in the URI.

Wondering what is recommended or the best options? These are some of the options which I can think of:

1. GET /customers/me
2. GET /customers/self
3. GET /customers/this

I have used 'me' a few times and the API consumers were fine with this. Thoughts?

Comment: This was discussed in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520372/designing-uri-for-current-logged-in-user-in-rest-applications.

Comment: I agree with /me.

Comment: The question is opinion-based as all approaches are valid and there are no specific restrictions.