# Proper REST response for current user when no user is logged in

Tags: rest, http, get

I have an endpoint that requests the current logged in user.

`GET /user/current`
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520372/designing-uri-for-current-logged-in-user-in-rest-applications)

If a user is found, the server sends `200 OK` and the user object.

But what if no one is logged in? Should the server send back `200 Ok` with an empty object?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746894/what-is-the-proper-rest-response-code-for-a-valid-request-but-an-empty-data) asked a similar question:

> For example you run a GET request for users/9 but there is no user with id #9. Which is the best response code?

The top answer was `404 Not Found`. But this doesn't seem correct to me for a current user request with no logged in user. In this case the answer was found- the answer is that no user is logged in.

Comment: Whose making the request ?

Comment: @PDHide My react frontend is making the request to render the frontend differently based on if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: @Deshiell underwhat identity does the api uses an authentication ? please see my answer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by under what "identity". But your answer below was helpful in explaining the different possibilities.

Comment: Means is there a authentication requirement or anyone can use that endpoint to see current users without authenticating

Comment: in this case anyone can use it to see if there is a user associated with the session.

Comment: @Then 401 is never applicable in your case 204 would be more apt

Comment: What about `403 Forbidden`?

Comment: @JoelFan After looking into it a bit, it seems to me it wouldn't it not be a 4xx response since it isn't a client error. The endpoint is meant to sometimes return that no one is logged in. So requesting the endpoint when a client isn't logged in isn't a client error.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss so 200 then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 would be valid only when authorization is required for making that call to that end point and it was not provided.

If that's an endpoint which doesn't require authentication then 404 is correct

You can also use 200 with current user as null if the response is usually a json string . If it's usually a json array return empty array with status 200 .

You can also use 204 no content

Comment: Why are you not recommending `403 Forbidden`?

Comment: @Joel because that's a open api that doesn't have any authorization or authentication ,  401 for authentication error and 403 is for authorization errors

Comment: Aa this api doesn't have authorization and authentication , both 401 and 403 is not applicable

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want `401 Unauthorized`

Comment: Oh yeah sort of makes sense, although I thought 401 were for protected routes and I hadn't really thought of it as a protected route. The 'user/current' endpoint is for helping the frontend know when to render an 'edit profile' button for example. Do you think it still makes sense to put to 401 Unauthorized in that case?

Comment: `RFC 7235` states: "The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not   been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for  the target resource."  It's very general.

Comment: If you want to strictly conform to the HTTP standard, whenever you respond with a 401 you must also include a `WWW-Authenticate` header that directs the client with how to resolve the authentication problem, with a value like: `Basic realm="Please login"`