# How to set permissions classes for UserList in a secure way

Tags: django-rest-framework, view, permissions, django-users

With this implementation, the entire Userlist is visible for anyone in the API endpoint. If I change the permission classes to IsAdmin for instance, users does not have access to their own user. What would be a secure way to only return the current user? Is it possible to filter out just that user within the get_queryset() function?

```
class UserList(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.serializer_class = UserGetSerializer
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = get_user_model().objects.all()

        if self.request.user:
            # Return the currently logged in user
            status = self.request.query_params.get("user", None)
            if status and status == "current":
                qs = get_user_model().objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
            return qs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you already accomplished your goal - you filter properly in `get_queryset`. Here's our implementation in [`Djoser`](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/b648b07dc2da7dab4c00c1c39af3d6ec53f58eb6/djoser/views.py#L60-L65) which is the most popular REST Auth lib for DRF.

Notice we have `/me` endpoint which is very common for asking for "yourself". For more info have a look at [Designing URI for current logged in user in REST applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520372/designing-uri-for-current-logged-in-user-in-rest-applications) question.

Anyway, everything user related is often weird. If I was trying to implement what you do I'd probably raise `NotFound` in `get_queryset` because in reality you don't need it.

If your goal is to return user data when he requests GET `user` resource without `pk`, something like that should work

```
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and afaik `create` doesn't need a `queryset`. For username/mail duplication add validators in the serializer.