# Is it correct to use self/current in a rest api url?

Tags: rest, http, url

For example let's say I have a url like `/projects/{projectId}/progress`.

Now, lets say a user can only be in one project. if the server already knows which project the user belongs to based on the context, do we need to pass the projectId or can we put the url as `/projects/current/progress` since we wouldn't be using the projectId even if it is passed.

Just want to know if it is a good practice or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resource can have multiple identifiers and nothing stops you from using a static mapping such as `/projects/{projectId}/progress` and a mapping that depends on a context such as `/projects/current/progress`.

A similar topic has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42389994/1426227), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35724570/1426227) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36522727/1426227).

Comment: Thank you very much @Cassio.